# Codeigniter upload image, then manipulate the image 3 times

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I am working on a gallery concept for something I am building up, and I am trying to figure out what would be my best approach at taking an image file uploaded to the server, and then converting it 3 times to different sizes within a set ratio with a max height or width. Depending on which is greater.

So the upload class, and image manipulation class are pretty straight forward on a one to one basis, though I know you can loop through an array and process things over and over. However, the tricky part is the 3 different sizes.

Essentially I plan to take the uploaded file and store it in a different directory than uploaded to with a new name and all else we will call that dir "org". Then I want to take this original, keeping the file name consistant with the original after renaming it, and then resize the original within a certain ratio with a max size of either certain width or height pending on which is greater. Which the image class handles, now the part thats confusing me, is how do I do this 3 times one smaller then the next. I want a "lrg", "med", "sml" folder set. Would I build those into the same function some how or would I pass one upon completion to the next function and so on? If its all in the same function, then thats where I am confused to how I should handle this.

Also for reference I haven't tried much outside of the standard information found on the CI docs, as I am trying to think this through before getting deep into the code and finding out it wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try timthumb insted of storing x3 elements.

this way you store Org. image and just in case you need specific size it process and store in cache folder for specific time in case you need same image again.

http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/